# Parsing array C++

Tags: c++, c++98

Hello guys how can i do this on C++ (98).
It's working good on visual studio or something, but on place where i want to use it doesn't work.

https://image.prntscr.com/image/loIxb-YRRiGh9XAFmZ_0dA.png

I'm trying to send multiple functions with other values in array like:

```
Print(xx, parse_array()); // No elements in parsearray all will be 0
Print(xx, parse_array(25)); // First element [0] will be 25, rest of them 0.



int * parse_array(int val1 = 0, int val2 = 0, int val3 = 0, int val4 = 0)
{
    int m_pDataArray[4] = {
        val1, val2, val3, val4
    };

    return m_pDataArray;
}

void Print(bool notImportant, int m_pDataArray[4])
{
    printf("m_pDataArray 0: %d", m_pDataArray[0]);
    printf("m_pDataArray 1: %d", m_pDataArray[1]);
    printf("m_pDataArray 2: %d", m_pDataArray[2]);
    printf("m_pDataArray 3: %d", m_pDataArray[3]);
}

Print(true, parse_array(10, 20, 30);
Print(true, parse_array(10);
Print(true, parse_array());
```

Comment: Describe your problem. Don't just say "it doesn't work" - define "*it*". What did you want it to do that it does not? And don't link to external images; put all relevant information *in the question* as *text*.

Comment: Sorry, i edited first pot some sec ago and i attached a photo. https://image.prntscr.com/image/loIxb-YRRiGh9XAFmZ_0dA.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the address of a local variable in `parse_array`. This is undefined behavior, the object `int m_pDataArray[4]` no longer exists after you've returned from your function, the pointer you return is immediately invalidated. Undefined behavior can do anything, including work sometimes on some computer but not on another computers, like you've described.

`int []` does not have value semantics, you cannot return it easily. Use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead.

```
#include <array>

std::array<int, 4> parse_array(int val1 = 0, int val2 = 0, int val3 = 0, int val4 = 0)
{
    std::array<int, 4> m_pDataArray = {
        val1, val2, val3, val4
    };

    return m_pDataArray;
}
```

Otherwise, you will need to return dynamically allocated buffers and then remember to delete them. The easiest way would be to use `std::unique_ptr` but those don't exist in C++98.

Edit : It seems I forgot that `std::array` was added in C++ 11. You can get the same results with [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> parse_array(int val1 = 0, int val2 = 0, int val3 = 0, int val4 = 0)
{
    std::vector<int> m_pDataArray;
    m_pDataArray.push_back(val1);
    m_pDataArray.push_back(val2);
    m_pDataArray.push_back(val3);
    m_pDataArray.push_back(val4);

    return m_pDataArray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer Francois, but i'm on c++98...doesn't exist a really method for what i want..? or maybe like i can do it with a vector or i dont know..

std::vector<int> parse_array(int a = 0, int b = 0, int c = 0, int d = 0)
{
    std::vector<int> m_vec_data;
    m_vec_data.push_back(a);
    m_vec_data.push_back(b);
    m_vec_data.push_back(c);
    m_vec_data.push_back(d);
    return m_vec_data;
}

void Print(std::vector<int> m_vec_data)
{
 for (int i = 0; i < m_vec_data.size(); i++)
  printf("m_pDataArray i: %d \n", m_vec_data[i]);
}

Comment: @Dr.Vendetta Updated. If you can, look into upgrading your compiler. The improves from C++98 to C++11 is truly enormous, the way of doing things changed completely.

Comment: Thanks bro, works perfectly, god bless you!